# What is the name of this house plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

What is the name of this plant?
I try to find the name but I don’t know how
[image: Dieffenbachia]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a dieffenbachia. It's a very easy houseplant to grow. Keep it in indirect light and don't water it too much - water it only when the pot is really light when you pick it up.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn’t know that. Thank you

Comment: Is it indirect but bright? Or indirect not so bright?

Comment: It can be indirect and not so bright. The plants are technically poisonous if eaten, but I've never heard of a severe poisoning from it. We had a cat who liked to chew on it occasionally, but she never had ill effects.

Comment: My dieffenbachia suffered until I moved it into surprisingly dim light, across the room from a South facing window.  Now it thrives!  The plant acts as a mild irritant and muscle relaxant, both of which can make it hard to speak after exposure.  I've been exposed before and it felt like a very mild, unpleasant Novocain after the dentist.